# Google app engine: Queries

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have a table Foo where my foos are stored and if I log in via browser and list all my foos there is one Foo with ID=12.
Then I have this code:

```
logging.info(fid)
q = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Foo WHERE ID = :1", fid)
logging.info(list(q))
```

which prints

```
12
[]
```

If I do `q.fetch(4)` it still gives me index out of range.
What am I doing wrong? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
get_by_id
```

is what I was looking for!

Answer (score 3):

Read the [doc](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstarted/usingdatastore.html). You can't query with a raw ID, you need to create a Key object.

Comment: doesn't mention that in the doc here: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queries.html

Comment: You're right, it's not there. That's kinda lame. It's also kinda lame that you can't write it the way you want. Either way, the doc I linked shows you how to do it.

Comment: Thanks, I have found the answer here on SO in the meantime!

Comment: This is because "ID" isn't a property of your entity.

Comment: @Wooble, I understand the reason, that doesn't mean I have to like it :)

Comment: @jiggy I'm not sure what you think the answer _should_ be. Should everything that looks like it might refer to a key ('key', 'KEY', '__key__', 'id', 'ID', '__id__', 'my_primary_key') be reserved to refer to the ID? There are standard ways to do this - they're just not what the OP assumed was the way to do it.